# How to identify which child LinearLayout clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
whilc(rs.next()){
data_big_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
data_big_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
data_big_params.setMargins(0,15,0,0);
data_big_layout.setLayoutParams(data_big_params);
data_big_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
data_big_layout.setWeightSum(20);
data_big_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
data_big_layout.setTag(rs.getInt(1));
data_big_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ID: "+data_big_layout.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           name.setText("Clicked ID: " + data_big_layout.getTag());
       }
});
detail_data_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,8.0f);
detail_data_layout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
detail_data_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
detail_data_layout.setPadding(50,0,0,0);

lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
name = new TextView(this);
name.setLayoutParams(lparams);
name.setText("ID(get from rs.next): " + rs.getString(1));
name.setTextSize(24);
name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
detail_data_layout.addView(name);
scroll_view_child.addView(data_big_layout); //scroll_view_child is a LinearLayout
}
```

Hi all, I have a problem cannot solve. The above code will generate two LinearLayout with the onclick function. However, the onclick function cannot identify which one I was clicked.

The two tags I set should be "1" and "2" in the first and second LinearLayout, but all LinearLayout will show "2" when I click it. How can I solve this problem? thanks!

I modified some code for testing, the rs.next can surely get the ID "1" and "2", but when I click the LinearLayout(no matter which layout I was clicked), only the second one will change the Textview.
Also the getTag() is only showing "2" no matter which LinearLayout I was clicked.

ps: some textview and imageview codes are skipped

Before click:

[image]

After clicked(no matter which layout I click):

[image]

Comment: what this code do? "rs.getInt(1)" it allways get same int

Comment: This code is a resultset storing the data which is from the database. The rs.getInt(1) means getting the first value of the resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rely on the `LinearLayout` variable name to get the tag value. Instead, you need to rely on the `View` inside click listener method:

```
data_big_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ID: "+ v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           name.setText("Clicked ID: " + v.getTag());
       }
});
```

Comment: @AlanLam: You're welcome! If this solve the problem, please mark as accepted answer. Or if you have an answer, you can create an answer then mark it as an accepted answer. ;)